# Remove rows from dataframe where var less than max(var) for each unique date

Tags: r, dataframe

Apologies if this has been asked but I couldn't find an existing solution.

Suppose a dataframe `d` as follows

```
+-------------------------------+
|  date        |  var1  | var2  | 
+-------------------------------+
|  2019/01/01  |  100   | abc   |
|  2019/01/01  |  102   | def   |
|  2019/01/02  |  99    | ghi   |
|  2019/01/02  |  98    | jkl   |
|  2019/01/03  |  100   | mno   |
|  2019/01/04  |  105   | pqr   |
|  2019/01/04  |  98    | stu   |
|  2019/01/04  |  110   | vwx   |
+-----------------------------+
```

With associated dput()

```
d <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17898, 17898, 
17899, 17900, 17900, 17900), class = "Date"), var1 = c(100, 102, 
99, 98, 100, 105, 98, 110), var2 = structure(1:8, .Label = c("abc", 
"def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx"), class = "factor")),      
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to remove records from `d` based on three requirements:

1. Only one record shall remain for each unique date
2. The record selected per unique date is max(var1) across all records of the same date in `d`
3. I want to keep var2 (and any other columns within the real dataset)

Thus, the valid required output would be

```
+----------------------------------+
|  Date      |  var1   | var2      | 
+----------------------------------+
|  01/01/19  |  102    | def       |
|  02/01/19  |  99     | ghi       |
|  03/01/19  |  100    | mno       |
|  04/01/19  |  110    | vwx       |
+----------------------------------+
```

Thank you for any help. Please advise if question could be worded better to make it useful for others.

Comment: I think the wording is pretty clear and great that you shared a reproducible sample of your data.

Comment: @akrun I am sure, you are aware but FYI I tagged this 18 mins ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146920/how-to-replace-the-first-value-of-each-group/54146945#54146945 Dupe is a dupe irrespective of anybody who answers. :) I don't look at who has answered the question before marking it as duplicate. Let me know if I have marked any dupe incorrectly, I would be happy to correct it.

Comment: @akrun I see the <s>double standard</s> inconsistency  but from what I understood from the discussion this week was that duplicated question should always be marked as duplicate. So the issue/mistake is answering (which I did here without thinking about it).

Comment: @snoram I am just saying :=). I have no problem with being tagged as dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, .SD[which.max(var1)], by = date]

         date var1 var2
1: 2019-01-01  102  def
2: 2019-01-02   99  ghi
3: 2019-01-03  100  mno
4: 2019-01-04  110  vwx
```

A very *raw* translation into base `R` gives:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(d, d[["date"]]), 
    function(SD) SD[which.max(SD[["var1"]]), ]
  )   
)
```

Comment: This appears to work. Before I select as resolved, could you please clarify the portion of your code '.SD' and its function? Thank you

Comment: basically `.SD` is another `data.table` with all the variables except, `date`. See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clarifying. Makes sense.

Comment: For further illustration try `d[, nrow(.SD), by = date]`.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   slice(which.max(var1))
```